# gpiozero -> MotionSensor and LED

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpiozero

I am trying to follow [this](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#motion-sensor) example.  Everything works fine as expected with the following two lines

```
pir.when_motion = led.on
pir.when_no_motion = led.off
```

but things stop working when I assign an event handler to `pir.when_motion`

I can see function, `turnOnLed`, and `turnOffLed` getting invoked but can't see LED turning on and off.

Below is my code.  Am I missing anything?

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor , LED
from signal import pause

import time

pir = MotionSensor(4)
led = LED(16)
def logMessage(msg):
            print(msg)
    def turnOnLed():
            logMessage('About to turn on LED...')
            led.on
            logMessage('LED turned on...')
    def turnOffLed():
            logMessage('About to turn off LED...')
            led.off
            logMessage('LED turned off...')
    def myfun():
            logMessage('Motion detected...')
    
    
    pir.when_motion = led.on         #If I replace led.on with event handler trunOnLed,  I cant see LED switching on.
    pir.when_no_motion = led.off
    logMessage('Before pause')
    pause()
```

Also, I have noticed that `pir.when_no_motion` event is getting triggered immediately after about 4 seconds of `pir.when_motion` even, if there is a continuous motion.  Any pointers on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It was a very small mistake.

Inside function `turnOnLed` I should have invoked function `led.on`

Fixed issue by replacing `led.on` with `led.on()`